# Use DataTemplate inside another DataTemplate?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-5.0

I have 2 lists on a view and I want them to share same DataTemplate.

First list can use this DataTemplate directly and second list need to use it under specific conditions, so in first case I have XAML like this and it works:

```
<ListBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TrackedAssetTemplate}">
```

In second case I have something like this but can't make it work..

```
<m:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Canvas
                            m:MapLayer.Position="{Binding Location}">
                            <Button
                                Visibility="{Binding IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource BoolToReverseVisibilityConverter}}"
                                Width="{Binding PushpinWidth}" Height="{Binding PushpinWidth}"
                                Style="{StaticResource LooklessButtonStyle}"
                                Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectedPushpinChangedCommand, ElementName=LayoutRoot}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                Cursor="Hand">
                                <Ellipse
                                Width="{Binding PushpinWidth}" Height="{Binding PushpinWidth}" Stroke="Black" Fill="{Binding IsGPSDataRecent, Converter={StaticResource BoolToGreenRedBrushConverter}}" StrokeThickness="1">
                                    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DeviceId}" />
                                    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                </Ellipse>
                            </Button>
                          <ContentControl
Visibility="{Binding IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"                                 
DataTemplate="{StaticResource TrackedAssetTemplate}" />
```

So, my idea is that first lisbox have straight template. I can use same data template when item selected on a map, otherwise I show button. I tried to wrap template on map inside `ContentControl` but it didn't work.

So, question is how to wrap data template inside datatemplate?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need to use one datatemplate inside other. You can style the item to use trigger to change the datatemplate of item. Something like

```
 <Style x:Key="ContentPresenterStyle"
           TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}" >
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate"
                        Value="{StaticResource DefaultStyleTemplate}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, ,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type MapListBoxItem}}}"  Value="False">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate"
                        Value="{StaticResource TrackedAssetTemplate}" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

You might have missed binding the Content of the inner ContentControl to the data context.

```
<ContentControl Content={Binding .}
    Visibility="{Binding IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" 
    DataTemplate="{StaticResource TrackedAssetTemplate}" />
```